# Storing list data into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert some data in a list to a dictionary. However, I want this dictionary to have multiple keys with multiple values, for example:

The list:

```
    titles = [ "title1", "title2" ]
    ids = [ 1, 2 ]
```

The dictionary:

```
    dictionary = { "title" : "title1", "title2", "id" : 1, 2 }
```

Sort of like a JSON idea...
There are actually quite a few entries in the lists, so I can't do them each manually. I could use a loop, I suppose?

Comment: Could you please show us this list?

Comment: also it is not valid. "title2" has no key (or value, depending on what you want it to be)

Comment: If you already have the lists, why not `d = {"title": titles, "id": ids}`?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['title'].append('title1')
>>> d['title'].append('title2')
>>> print d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'title': ['title1', 'title2']})
```

In your case, however, you can simply do:

```
dictionary = {'title':titles, 'id':ids}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can link items together using tuples also if you'd prefer (using parentheses). This way you can access multiple items with one key. I don't quite know if this is what you're looking for, but I hope it helps.

```
dictionary = { "title" : ("title1", "title2"), "id" : (1, 2) }
#dictionary[title][0] returns "title1"
#dictionary[title][1] returns "title2"
```

More info on tuples:
http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
>>> titles = ["t1","t2"]
>>> ids = [1,2]
>>> dct = {"titles": titles, "ids":ids}
>>> dct
{'titles': ['t1', 't2'], 'ids': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using dict setdefault function

```py
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('title', []).append('title1')
>>> d.setdefault('title', []).append('title2')
>>> d
{'title': ['title1', 'title2']}
```